# How to get rid of absolute paths from a file generated by docker-compose config?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I have a ton of docker-compose files. Some defining my microservices, some defining the infrastructural pieces, like db, message bus etc. I need to merge them all into one, big docker-compose.yml file, so that I can easily run it via my CI/CD pipeline. I wrote this shell script to do so, but it seems the `docker-compose config` command generates a file with absolute paths:

```
#!/bin/bash

ymls=`ls **/docker-compose.*.yml`
compose_string=""

for file in $ymls
do
    compose_string="${compose_string} -f ${file} --project-directory ."
done

echo $compose_string

docker-compose $compose_string config > docker-compose.merged.yml
```

This gives me the below file contents (shortened for brevity):

```
services:
  curator-services:
    build:
      args:
        ELASTIC_PASSWORD: them-pass
      context: E:\repos\them-project\devops\curator
  manager-acl-app:
    build:
      context: E:\repos\them-project
      dockerfile: services/ThemProject.Services.ManagerAcl/Dockerfile
```

Now, the easy solution would be to just run a regexp or something and substitute whatever is in the same line as the word `context`. The problem with that approach is that I keep my infrastructural definitions in another folder than my microservices Dockerfiles, so the `context` for the curator-services piece should be `context: curator/` and for the manager-acl-app it should be `context: ../`. Is there a way around those absolute paths with `docker-compose config`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--project-directory`  option with `docker-compose config`.

Change your script to below

```
#!/bin/bash

ymls=`ls docker-compose.*.yml`
compose_string=""
DIR_PATH="." #Change it to Project Directory or current directory
for file in $ymls
do
    compose_string="${compose_string} -f ${file} --project-directory $DIR_PATH"
done

docker-compose ${compose_string} config > docker-compose.yml
```

> Ref:- https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/

Please check `--project-directory` in the above link

Comment: If I use it, an empty file is generated.

Comment: Can you please paste the output ?

Comment: Sorry, I had to take care of something else. Answering your question: the output is a list of available docker-compose commands

Comment: I've just updated my original question. Btw. the flag was --project-directory, not --project-dir